# Compiling example UBOOT standalone application

Tags: compilation, cross-compiling, bootloader, u-boot

I am trying to build a UBOOT standalone application.

Looking at the README and the minimal documentation on this, I am curious.

Is the hello world example standalone, simply just compiled/cross-compiled the same way any other application is? Obviously for whatever the target architecture is.

Do I need to use makeelf or something to get a .bin file?

Comment: *"Is the hello world example standalone, simply just compiled/cross-compiled the same way..."* -- Use the same toolchain that you use for building U-Boot.  *"Do I need to use makeelf or something to get a .bin file?"* -- No, the **makefile** has a rule for the **.bin** file.  Be sure to define an appropriate CONFIG_STANDALONE_LOAD_ADDR.

Comment: *"I assume I need #define CONFIG_STANDALONE_LOAD_ADDR 0x0ADDRESS in /include/configs/board_name.h???"* -- Yes.